# "Could not find MDB Tools, which are required to build gmdb2" on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, package-management

I'm trying to install `gmdb2` from the AUR repo using `yay` on Arch Linux, and I've already installed `mdbtools`:

```bsh
yay -S gmdb2
```

I'm encountering the following error:

```
configure: error: Could not find MDB Tools, which are required to build gmdb2.
```

As mentioned, `mdbtools` is already installed. Is there any solution or something to do with it?

Comment: From your description, I guess it could be some package named `mdbtools-dev` (or similar) missing, that means the dev tools for other programs to depend on it. But I can't be sure now, you can check it.

Comment: there is no such `mdbtools-dev` instead there is `mdbtools-beta` which are in conflict, and you were right installing `beta` has solved the problem, i thought that `beta` would have some bugs so i ignored it and went to `stable`, so thank you sir for your time

Comment: @thanasisp or DevProd, could one of you please whip that into an answer so we can mark the question as solved?

Comment: I've answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `mdbtools` then install `mdbtools-beta`

```bsh
yay -Runsc mdbtools && yay -S mdbtools-beta
```

or install `mdbtools-beta` then when asked about removing conflict packages accept the removal of `mdbtools`

```
yay -S mdbtools-beta
```